# How to draw WPF 3D Cross section?

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics, 3d

My project have to work like this https://www.geogebra.org/m/HSgSE469. But I don't know how to do in WPF.Anyone may be create a small example? Tks

Comment: Which specific aspect of this is the problem? Everything? What is your starting point - you have what now, exactly?  Unless you narrow the scope of your question to something specific, I think you'll find your question closed as too broad a scope.

Answer (score 0):

Just select the object you want to change the opacity of, then go to the 'Brush' tab in the properties, and adjust the Alpha level for the relevant brush (probably either background or foreground). You'll also need to add the tag `AllowsTransparency="True"` to the window.